# Drawing Application how to save drawing in android phone memory

Tags: android, actionscript-3, png

I try to save in png file format. It dose't work when i try to publish to android phone. i do not understand how android phone path from folder to folder work. how do i make it work...

I try the same Actionscript 3 and publish it on my pc and it work....

pls help. sorry bad grammar.

```
function export():void
        {



        var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(480, 800);

        bmd.draw(board);

        var ba:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bmd);

        var file:FileReference = new FileReference();

        file.save(ba, "MyDrawing.png");

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the way i save images on Android:

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("MyDrawing.png");
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeBytes(ba, 0, ba.length);
stream.close();
```

Comment: where dose the "MyDrawing.png" file save in the phone location? I cant find it? It should be in the phone folder somewhere right?

Comment: it's hidden inside the app storage directory. this doc should explain it: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f82c4ee412b1275403b-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f82c4ee412b1275403b-7ffd

Comment: you may want to use: File.documentsDirectory if you want the user to be able to find it.

Comment: thanks for the link bnns. i didnt realise File.desktopDirectory etc would point to sdcard on android - thats very useful.

Comment: i still cant find the png file. it dose not show any error. i have read some information that i need a permission to allow this feature to work. do you guys have any idea how to do so??

Comment: you may need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: so do i need to write something in the actionscriept or what?

Comment: add this to your app descriptor file: <android><manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest android:installLocation="auto"><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/></manifest>]]></manifestAdditions></android>

Answer (score 0):

why you wants to save  your drawing in phone memory ?How can u tackle when memory size exceeds ?

Anyway Refer this Link,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal